# How to configure web.xml to change Tomcat default landing page to a JSP

Tags: jsp, tomcat

I have a simple jsp page running under Tomcat to display a report, the problem is how to configure web.xml to point the default landing page to this JSP.

Web.xml is empty so it currently only works if named index.jsp in the root of the war file, but I want it with a different name under WEB-INF.  Also should I call a java class first before invoking this? I need to retrieve a database connection rather than store database credentials in the JSP.  No web framework like struts is being used.

Answer (score 2):

There are two ways to do so.

**Method 1: Reconfigure web.xml**

You probably see something like this in the *web.xml*:

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.htm</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

You can reconfigure the landing page like so:

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file>index.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file>index.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

Or you can make it custom like this:

```
<welcome-file-list>
    <welcome-file><TARGETPAGE>.jsp</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file><TARGETPAGE>.html</welcome-file>
    <welcome-file><TARGETPAGE>.html</welcome-file>
</welcome-file-list>
```

This makes sure the landing page is *index.jsp*.

**Method 2: Redirect**

Add this to your default landing page:

```
<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="0; URL='<TARGETPAGE>.jsp'" />
```